# PHP mail MYSQL DB

Tags: php, mysql, email, mailing

Hello people from stackoverflow.
I need some help with an PHP script I have..
The problem is that it isn't sending any email. I tried a couple of other topics but it didn't work quite well..

Here is my mailing (Config is already been included) code:

```
    <?php
$sql = "SELECT email FROM users";
    $res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res) )
    {
         $area .= $row['email']. ", ";  

    }
?>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){


$email_list = explode(',', $area);
$message = $_REQUEST['bericht'];
$to = $email_list;

@mail($to,"Message","$message". "\n\n". "Met vriendelijke groet,". "\n". "Brian","From: noreply@$siteurl");
}
?>
```

What is wrong with this code? Thanks!

Comment: For a start, you're suppressing error messages from mail with the @. Are you actually getting any email addresses from your query? What is in `$to` - it looks like, with the `explode()`, that it's an array; have you checked the documentation to see if you can pass an array as the To list?

Comment: @andrewsi I created another php file just an normal one to see if its rowing the Email. And it does row the Email I see 4 emails from the DB now

Comment: @andrewsi thanks I found it thanks to your help and from mjayt.. I own you guys one! You guys made my day ;-)

Comment: Hey, don't leave us in suspense - what was the issue? :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <?php
$sql = "SELECT email FROM users";
    $res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res) )
    {
         $area .= $row['email']. ", ";  

    }
?>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$message = $_REQUEST['bericht'];
$to = $area;

@mail($to,"Message","$message". "\n\n". "Met vriendelijke groet,". "\n". "Brian","From: noreply@$siteurl");
```

Take out the explode and try with just the code above. mail() wants multiple address in the to field separated by commas, so it doesn't make any sense to explode them on commas. As andrewsi said, that is then passing to the mail function as an array.

Comment: Well thats for the quick comment.. I tried that one already with no luck at all..

Comment: @user3096407 - start off with the basics, in that case. Replace `$to` with your email address, and see if it works when that's the only change. If it does, then `var_dump($to)` and see what's in there, and whether it looks good.

Comment: @mjayt thanks I found it thanks to your help and from andrewsi.. I own you guys one! You guys made my day ;-)